# Want to build a VF page showing steps in different sections. What would be best approach?

Tags: visualforce

Don't want it to be like wizard. All steps should be in one page. There are also some dependent steps. Which would have something like check-box. If it is checked only then next step should appear.

Comment: Yes it seems doable. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<apex:pageBlock?` to show multiple sections. They also rendered based on the checkbox condition means you can control the rendering of pageblock when checkbox is checked else not display the pageblock.

Hope it helps you.